# Curve described by a point inside an ellipse

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

It's well known that a point inside a circle rotating on a line describes a trochoid of parametric equation:
$$x=c_0\phi-c_1\sin(\phi)$$
$$y=c_2-c_3\cos(\phi)$$ 
in which the constant $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$
are depending on its position on the diameter of the circle. My question is: if we have an ellipse with axis $a$ and $b$ and a point inside the ellipse, what is the parametric equation of the curve obtained rolling the ellipse on a line?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean a circle rolling on a line without slipping ?

Comment: @mercio: Yes. Exatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point is at the focus of the ellipse the curve is a Roulette of Delaunay:
Here is a link: http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/delaunay/delaunay.shtml

Comment: And if the point isn't in the focus of the ellipse?

Comment: At the center of a conic a Roulette of Sturm: http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/sturm/sturm.shtml

Comment: I see, but unfortunately the point could be located in every part inside the ellipse not necessarily in a 'particular' place like the foci or the axis or the center. Thank you anyway

Comment: Ah, the roulette of Alestra !

Comment: It sounds well !

Comment: Here is a paper on Arxiv which has a section devoted to roulettes of the conics : arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5681.pdf